# Manipulating model and then reflecting that within a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `LogoutModel` with one attribute. I want my `HomeController` to change this value and for the `View` to then show this value but it doesn't seem to be working. When the Logout View is displayed it shows: 'Goodbye Html.LabelFor(m => m.PreviouslyLoggedInUsername)'

LogoutModel:

```
public class LogoutModel
        {
            public string PreviouslyLoggedInUsername { get; set; }
        }
```

HomeController:

```
        public ActionResult Logout(HomeModels.LogoutModel model)
        {
            model.PreviouslyLoggedInUsername = previousLoggedIn;
            return View(model);
        }
```

View:

```
@using Ecommerce.Models
@model HomeModels.LogoutModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Logout";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Master.cshtml";
}

<h2>You have been logged out.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Goodbye </label>
                Html.LabelFor(m => m.PreviouslyLoggedInUsername)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

}

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: It just displays 'Goodbye Html.LabelFor(m => m.PreviouslyLoggedInUsername)' on the Logout View and not the actual username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place an `@` symbol before the `Html.LabelFor...`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Goodbye </label>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PreviouslyLoggedInUsername)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For reference, here's the [Razor syntax quick guide.](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)